# primary key in a SQLite table made of two columns

Tags: sqlite

I would like to make a primary key in a SQLite table made of two columns which work like this:

- Columns: `id1`, `id2`, `value`
- Multiple rows can share `id1`
- Multiple rows can share `id2`
- But only one row can share *both* `id1` *and* `id2`

I read a lot but all question I found told how to make two independent primary keys, but it is not my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

```
sqlite> create table t (f1 integer, f2 integer);
sqlite> create unique index i12 on t (f1, f2);
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE t (f1 integer, f2 integer);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i12 on t (f1, f2);
sqlite> insert into t values (1,2);
sqlite> insert into t values (1,3);
sqlite> insert into t values (2,2);
sqlite> insert into t values (1,2);
Error: columns f1, f2 are not unique
```

See the reference of [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html).